# Specifying the metadata in bulk import tool in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am trying to bulk import files into Alfresco repository with the Alfresco bulk import tool , and as per the different sources I am creating a metadata files  using shadow java property files in xml format. I have created a folder named bulkimport1 on my desktop and kept the metadata property files under it. I have created the metadata files as per [the Alfresco 4.0 Build Import Tool docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Fconcepts%2FBulk-Import-Tool.html)

I am using the Alfresco interface for uploading the folder as per the [docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Fconcepts%2FBulk-Import-Tool.html)

But I get the error as below

```
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 10090543 java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.alfresco.repo.bulkimport.metadataloaders.AbstractMapBasedMetadataLoader.loadMetadata(AbstractMapBasedMetadataLoader.java:117)
at org.alfresco.repo.bulkimport.impl.AbstractNodeImporter.loadMetadata(AbstractNodeImporter.java:401)
at org.alfresco.repo.bulkimport.impl.StreamingNodeImporterFactory$StreamingNodeImporter.importImportableItemImpl(StreamingNodeImporterFactory.java:107)
at org.alfresco.repo.bulkimport.impl.AbstractNodeImporter.importImportableItem(AbstractNodeImporter.java:414)
at org.alfresco.repo.bulkimport.impl.MultiThreadedBulkFilesystemImporter$1.process(MultiThreadedBulkFilesystemImporter.java:120)
at org.alfresco.repo.bulkimport.impl.MultiThreadedBulkFilesystemImporter$1.process(MultiThreadedBulkFilesystemImporter.java:78)
at org.alfresco.repo.batch.BatchProcessor$TxnCallback.execute(BatchProcessor.java:712)
at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:433)
at org.alfresco.repo.batch.BatchProcessor$TxnCallback.run(BatchProcessor.java:756)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

at org.alfresco.repo.bulkimport.impl.StripingBulkFilesystemImporter.bulkImportImpl(StripingBulkFilesystemImporter.java:67)
at org.alfresco.repo.bulkimport.impl.AbstractBulkFilesystemImporter$3.execute(AbstractBulkFilesystemImporter.java:395)
at org.alfresco.repo.bulkimport.impl.AbstractBulkFilesystemImporter$3.execute(AbstractBulkFilesystemImporter.java:371)
at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:433)
at org.alfresco.repo.bulkimport.impl.AbstractBulkFilesystemImporter.bulkImport(AbstractBulkFilesystemImporter.java:370)
at org.alfresco.repo.bulkimport.impl.AbstractBulkFilesystemImporter$2$1.doWork(AbstractBulkFilesystemImporter.java:351)
at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:529)
at org.alfresco.repo.bulkimport.impl.AbstractBulkFilesystemImporter$2.run(AbstractBulkFilesystemImporter.java:347)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Kindly provide a solution to this . Also where do I keep the metadata files , inside the folder to be uploaded or somewhere else ?

Comment: Are you sure your metadata xml files are valid? My first guess is that you've created invalid files. See the [examples in the docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Fconcepts%2Fbulk-import-prepare-filesystem.html) to see what you need to be doing

Comment: thanks a lot.it was the date which was creating problems